# Crear un modulo (paquete) en python y compartirlo

Tags: python, pip

Me gustaría saber:

1. ¿Cómo se podría subir (empaquetar) y compartir un proyecto (paquete) de **Python** por internet?
2. ¿Dónde podría almacenarlo para que pudieran instalarlo fácilmente las personas?

Comment: ¿Compartir binarios? ¿Compartir código fuente? ¿Ambos?

Comment: Ambos, que la otra persona pudiera tener los códigos. Pero que al empaquetarlo y instalarlo se instale los módulos que use tambien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para compartir un proyecto de Python con la comunidad, puedes hacerlo a través de **pypy** y el comando `pip`. Aquí dejo los pasos

## 1. Registrarte en pypy.

Tienes que crearte una cuenta de usuario [aquí](https://pypi.org/account/register/). Si quieres poder operar y subir paquetes.

## 2. Instalar los paquetes necesarios para crear un módulo.

- Comprobar que tienes **pip** `pip -V` si no lo tienes instalarlo. (como se realice la instalación, dependerá del SO)
- Instalar **setuptools**: es un paquete diseñado para crear y distribuir librerías.  `pip install setuptools`
- Instalar **Wheel** `pip install wheel`: lo que hace es crear un fichero `.whl` que hace que tu paquete pueda ser instalado con el comando `pip install`
- Instalar **Twine** `pip install twine`: Crea una conexión segura enter tu ordenador y pypy. Además en ocasiones falla, por lo que tienes que  instalar también **Tqdm** `pip install tqdm`, que tan solo es un paquete que crea barras de progreso para que puedas ver como van la ejecución de programas.

**La mayoría de estos programas si estás en un entorno que usas, ya vienen instalados normalmente, en ese caso, utiliza el comando:** `pip install --upgrade` con cada uno de ellos, para utilizar su última versión.

## 3. Crea tu paquete

Crea el paquete que quieras usar y asegúrate de tener permisos de ejecución. En linux por ejemplo se dan con `chmod +x <nombre_ejecutable>`.

Dentro del paquete crea el archivo **setup.py**, aquí te pongo un ejemplo:

```
import setuptools

#Si tienes un readme
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()


setuptools.setup(
     name='mi_paquete',  #nombre del paquete
     version='0.1', #versión
     scripts=['my_ejecutable.py'] , #nombre del ejecutable
     author="Alberto Rubiales", #autor
     author_email="albertorubialest@gmail.com", #email
     description="Un paquete para traducir a números romanos", #Breve descripción
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown", #Incluir el README.md si lo has creado
     url="https://github.com/usuario/nombre_del_paquete", #url donde se encuentra tu paquete en Github
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(), #buscamos todas las dependecias necesarias para que tu paquete funcione (por ejemplo numpy, scipy, etc.)
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 ) #aquí añadimos información sobre el lenguaje usado, el tipo de licencia, etc.
```

Para tener la clásica licencia de uso MIT, puedes encontrar el prototipo [aquí](https://github.com/javatechy/dokr/blob/master/LICENSE)

Esto anterior es un ejemplo de como hacerlo, se pueden agregar más opciones en **classifiers**, no poner la descripción larga, etc.

## 4. Compilar tu paquete

Te sitúas dentro de tu paquete y ejecutas el siguiente comando: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. Esto te generará los siguientes ficheros.

- build: contiene la información del paquete
- dist: contiene un fichero `.whl` como comenté anteriormente hace que se puedan instalar los paquetes con pip `pip install nombre_paquete.whl`
- project.egg.info: contiene información sobre el paquete creado, que es usado por el archivo setup.py

## 5. Comprobar que el paquete funciona en local.

Dirígete al archivo `.whl` mencionado anteriormente que se encuentra en la carpeta **dist** y ejecuta el siguiente comando `python -m pip install nombre_del_paquete.whl`. Si todo sale bien, instalarás tu propio paquete

## 6 Subir tu proyecto a pypy,

Subiendo tu proyecto conseguirás que todos lo puedan instalar desde su ordenador personal. Para ello tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- Crear un archivo `.pypirc` en la carpeta raíz de tu módulo.
- Añadir a dicho fichero el siguiente contenido, con tu nombre de usuario de pypy.

```
[distutils] 
index-servers=pypi
[pypi] 
repository = https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ 
username =tu_nombre_de_usuario
```

- Por último ejecuta este comando, para subir tu proyecto a pypy.  `python -m twine upload dist/*`

Una vez seguidos estos pasos, ya podrás instalar tu paquete tu y cualquier persona que quiera con el comando `pip install` al igual que se hace con el resto de paquetes de Python!